# XAMARIN (C#) - Is There A Way To Underline A TextView Programmatically?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, textview

I know there are some other ways to do it (I think in Java you do something like this `.SetPaintFlags(Paint.Underline_Text_Flag);`) - and I do understand that it could be sort of emulated using the Draw Line and there is also a way to do it by predefining it in xml file as well.

**The question is how to accomplish it **programmatically** **in Xamarin (C#)?** There should be a property on the object or some way to set it**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most "Set" methods in Android are converted to C# Properties in Xamarin.  So

```
SetPaintFlags(Paint.Underline_Text_Flag);
```

becomes

```
my_object.PaintFlags = PaintFlags.UnderlineText;
```